# How do would I alphabetize the strings in my character array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, words

I've written a program to count the occurrences of letters and words from a string that the user enters. I have successfully gotten most of it to work now, however,  I must also alphabetize the words I have stored in my array of pointers. I saw a function void sortstring() that was supposed to to just this but it doesn't seem to work at all. How would I go about it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void findLetters(char *ptr);
void findWords(char *point);
void sort_string(char *p);

int main()
{
    char textStream[100]; //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'

    printf("enter some text\n");
    if (fgets(textStream, sizeof (textStream), stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
    {
        findLetters(textStream);
        findWords(textStream);
        sort_string(textStream);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fgets failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void findLetters(char *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
{
    int upLetters[26];
    int loLetters[26];
    int i;
    int index;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) // set array to all zero
    {
        upLetters[i] = 0;
        loLetters[i] = 0;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (ptr[i] != '\0') // loop until prt[i] is '\0'
    {
        if (ptr[i] >= 'A' && ptr[i] <= 'Z') //stores occurrences of uppercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'A';// subtract 'A' to get index 0-25
            upLetters[index]++;//add one
        }

        if (ptr[i] >= 'a' && ptr[i] <= 'z') //stores occurrences of lowercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'a';//subtract 'a' to get index 0-25
            loLetters[index]++;//add one
        }
        i++;//next character in ptr
    }
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Uppercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)//loop through 0 to 25
    {
        if (upLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'A'), upLetters[i]);
            // add 'A' to go from an index back to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Lowercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (loLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'a'), loLetters[i]);
            // add 'a' to go back from an index to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int space = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int len = strlen(point);
    char copy[50][100];
    char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) ";
    char **word;
    char *newpoint;
    char *newerpoint;
    char *token;
    int occur[50]; // will store number of occurances of each word

    for (; i < 50; i++) //sets all indexes to 0
    {
        occur[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //counts # of spaces between words
    {
        if ((point[i] == ' ') || (point[i] == ',') || (point[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    word = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(space+1)); //allocates memory to array according to number of words
    newpoint = malloc(strlen(point)+1);
    strcpy(newpoint, point);
    newerpoint = malloc(strlen(point) + 1);
    strcpy(newerpoint, point);
    token = strtok(newpoint, delim);

    for (k; k <= space && token != NULL; k++)
    {
        word[k] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(word[k], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        printf("%s\n", word[k]);
    }

    for (k = 0; k <= space; k++)
    {
        free(word[k]);
    }
}

void sort_string(char *p)
    {
        int c, d = 0, length;
        char *pointer, *result, ch;

        length = strlen(p);
        result = (char*)malloc(length + 1);

        pointer = p;

        for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c < length; c++)
            {
                if (pointer == ch)
                {
                    *(result + d) = *pointer;
                    d++;
                }
                pointer++;
            }
            pointer = p;
        }
        *(result + d) = '\0';

        strcpy(p, result);
        free(result);
    }
```

EDITED VERSION:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void findLetters(char *ptr);
void findWords(char *point);
int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b);


int main (void)
{
    char textStream[100] = {0};     //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'
    typedef unsigned int size_t;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf ("enter some text\n");
    if (fgets (textStream, sizeof textStream, stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
    {
        len = strlen (textStream);
        textStream[--len] = 0;      // strip newline from end of textStream

        findLetters (textStream);
        findWords (textStream);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fgets failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void findLetters(char *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
{
    int upLetters[26];
    int loLetters[26];
    int i;
    int index;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) // set array to all zero
    {
        upLetters[i] = 0;
        loLetters[i] = 0;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (ptr[i] != '\0') // loop until prt[i] is '\0'
    {
        if (ptr[i] >= 'A' && ptr[i] <= 'Z') //stores occurrences of uppercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'A';// subtract 'A' to get index 0-25
            upLetters[index]++;//add one
        }

        if (ptr[i] >= 'a' && ptr[i] <= 'z') //stores occurrences of lowercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'a';//subtract 'a' to get index 0-25
            loLetters[index]++;//add one
        }
        i++;//next character in ptr
    }
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Uppercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)//loop through 0 to 25
    {
        if (upLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'A'), upLetters[i]);
            // add 'A' to go from an index back to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Lowercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (loLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'a'), loLetters[i]);
            // add 'a' to go back from an index to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i, k, count, space;
    int len = strlen (point);
    char *delim = "\n { } . , ( ) ";
    char **word = NULL;
    char *newpoint = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;

    i = k = count = space = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //counts # of spaces between words
        if ((point[i] == ' ') || (point[i] == ',') || (point[i] == '.'))
            space++;

    word = malloc (sizeof *word * space + 1); //allocates memory to array according to number of words
    newpoint = malloc (strlen (point) + 1);
    strcpy (newpoint, point);
    token = strtok (newpoint, delim);

    printf ("\nSeparating and saving words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; token != NULL; k++)
    {
        word[k] = malloc (strlen (token) + 1);
        strcpy (word[k], token);
        token = strtok (NULL, delim);
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);
    }

    count = k;  /* save number of string in word */

    qsort (word, count, sizeof *word, compare_str);     /* sort the array of pointers */

    printf ("\nSorted words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);

    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        free(word[k]);
    }
}


int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

Comment: Can you use qsort()?  That might be the easiest way to get something sorted without writing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do get it working, I think you are in for a surprise. The `sort_string` function has nothing whatsoever to do with sorting **words in an array of pointers** instead, it sorts **characters in an array**. For example:

```
$ ./bin/str_sort_words

Enter a string: a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
  sorted words: aabcdeefghijklmnoooopqrrstuuvwxyz
```

Instead you need to sort the array of pointers with `qsort` so that you are actually sorting words instead of characters. To use `qsort` you must provide it a `compare` function so that it knows the size and number of items to sort. For an array of pointers, a `qsort` compare function looks like this:

```
/* qsort C-string comparison function */
int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

Then in your case, you must call it in the `findWords` function where the pointer array `word` lives as follows:

```
qsort (word, count, sizeof *word, compare_str);
```

(where `count` is your `space + 1` equivalent). Now before we look at the answer, you need to enable **Warnings** when you compile (which your code doesn't due to the pointer/int mismatch in `if (pointer == ch)` which should be `if (*pointer == ch)`.

But beyond that, compiling with warnings enabled would have pointed out a whole list of problems in `findWords`. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string.

Now let's look at changes to your code. **Always initialize All variables**:

```
char textStream[100] = {0};     //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'
size_t len = 0;
```

Next, when using `fgets` or `getline`, it is a good idea to strip the tailing `newline` so it isn't dangling off your strings:

```
if (fgets (textStream, sizeof textStream, stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
{
    len = strlen (textStream);
    textStream[--len] = 0;      // strip newline from end of textStream
    ...
```

Now, changes to `findWords`:

```
void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    // int j = 0;
    int space = 0;
    // int c = 0;
    int len = strlen(point);
    // char copy[50][100];
    char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) ";
    char **word = NULL;
    char *newpoint = NULL;
    char *newerpoint = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;
//     int occur[50]; // will store number of occurances of each word
// 
//     for (; i < 50; i++) //sets all indexes to 0
//     {
//         occur[i] = 0;
//     }


    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //counts # of spaces between words
    {
        if ((point[i] == ' ') || (point[i] == ',') || (point[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    word = malloc (sizeof *word * space + 1); //allocates memory to array according to number of words
    newpoint = malloc (strlen (point) + 1);
    strcpy (newpoint, point);
    newerpoint = malloc (strlen (point) + 1);
    strcpy (newerpoint, point);
    token = strtok (newpoint, delim);

    printf ("\nSeparating and saving words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; token != NULL; k++)
    {
        word[k] = malloc (strlen (token) + 1);
        strcpy (word[k], token);
        token = strtok (NULL, delim);
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);
    }

    count = k;  /* save number of string in word */

    qsort (word, count, sizeof *word, compare_str);     /* sort the array of pointers */

    printf ("\nSorted words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);

    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        free(word[k]);
    }
}
```

When you compile, there should be **NO** warnings:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o yourprog yourfile.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_find_ltr_words
enter some text
the quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog
Number of Occurrences of Uppercase letters


Number of Occurrences of Lowercase letters

a :     2
b :     1
c :     1
d :     2
e :     3
f :     1
g :     1
h :     1
i :     1
j :     1
k :     1
l :     1
m :     1
n :     1
o :     4
p :     1
q :     1
r :     2
t :     1
u :     2
v :     1
w :     1
x :     1
y :     1
z :     1


Separating and saving words in pointer array:

the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
a
lazy
dog


Sorted words in pointer array:

a
brown
dog
fox
jumped
lazy
over
quick
the
```

And as a final point. There is a **lot** of irrelevant code in your `findWords` function. I didn't take the time to strip it out because that wasn't preventing your sort of words. Your code with the modifications above compiles without warning. So I'll leave it up to you to go though `findWords` and get rid of what isn't needed.

---

**Full Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void findLetters(char *ptr);
void findWords(char *point);
void sort_string(char *p);
int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b);


int main (void)
{
    char textStream[100] = {0};     //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'
    size_t len = 0;

    printf ("enter some text\n");
    if (fgets (textStream, sizeof textStream, stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
    {
        len = strlen (textStream);
        textStream[--len] = 0;      // strip newline from end of textStream

        findLetters (textStream);
        findWords (textStream);
        sort_string (textStream);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fgets failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void findLetters(char *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
{
    int upLetters[26];
    int loLetters[26];
    int i;
    int index;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) // set array to all zero
    {
        upLetters[i] = 0;
        loLetters[i] = 0;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (ptr[i] != '\0') // loop until prt[i] is '\0'
    {
        if (ptr[i] >= 'A' && ptr[i] <= 'Z') //stores occurrences of uppercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'A';// subtract 'A' to get index 0-25
            upLetters[index]++;//add one
        }

        if (ptr[i] >= 'a' && ptr[i] <= 'z') //stores occurrences of lowercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'a';//subtract 'a' to get index 0-25
            loLetters[index]++;//add one
        }
        i++;//next character in ptr
    }
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Uppercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)//loop through 0 to 25
    {
        if (upLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'A'), upLetters[i]);
            // add 'A' to go from an index back to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Lowercase letters\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (loLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'a'), loLetters[i]);
            // add 'a' to go back from an index to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i, k, count, space;
    int len = strlen (point);
    char *delim = "{ } . , ( ) \n";
    char **word = NULL;
    char *newpoint = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;

    i = k = count = space = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //counts # of spaces between words
        if ((point[i] == ' ') || (point[i] == ',') || (point[i] == '.'))
            space++;

    word = malloc (sizeof *word * space + 1); //allocates memory to array according to number of words
    newpoint = malloc (strlen (point) + 1);
    strcpy (newpoint, point);
    token = strtok (newpoint, delim);

    printf ("\nSeparating and saving words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; token != NULL; k++)
    {
        word[k] = malloc (strlen (token) + 1);
        strcpy (word[k], token);
        token = strtok (NULL, delim);
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);
    }

    count = k;  /* save number of string in word */

    qsort (word, count, sizeof *word, compare_str);     /* sort the array of pointers */

    printf ("\nSorted words in pointer array:\n\n");
    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
        printf ("%s\n", word[k]);

    for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        free(word[k]);
    }
}

void sort_string(char *p)
{
    int c, d = 0, length;
    char *pointer, *result, ch;

    length = strlen(p);
    result = (char*)malloc(length + 1);

    pointer = p;

    for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < length; c++)
        {
            if (*pointer == ch)
            {
                *(result + d) = *pointer;
                d++;
            }
            pointer++;
        }
        pointer = p;
    }
    *(result + d) = '\0';

    strcpy(p, result);

    free(result);
}

/* qsort C-string comparison function */
int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

---

**Why you had an extra newline**

As mentioned in the comments and in the answer, it is **always** a good idea to strip the trailing `'\n'` from your strings when you are reading with `fgets` or `getline`. It will cause your character count in `len` to be off by `1` and then for your `space` count to be off by `1`. Now that in itself isn't a crime, it just causes you to allocate one more pointer than needed. However it has consequences due to your definition of:

```
char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) ";
```

Since you do not specify `'\n'` as a delimiter, `strtok` happily considers it as a separate word. This does cause problems with your sort as you now have a **blank line** appearing in your array of words. So you can either strip the newline after you read `textStream` or add `'\n'` to `delim` (or properly both).

```
char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) \n";
```

---

**Case Insensitive Sorting**

When wanting to sort without the effects of your LOCALE sorting capital letters first, etc. Use `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp`. So above, just change the `qsort` comparison to:

```
int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcasecmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

---

**strcasecmp on Windows**

`strcasecmp` is a non-standard function available on linux and not in windows. To include the same functionality use `stricmp` instead. See ([**MSDN stricmp**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx)).

Comment: I implemented the code as you out it and I get no errors or warnings, but the words don't actually get sorted.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have all your code posted? I'll take a look, but this is probably one of those times where there will be a subtle, but important difference.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look, In the mean time, look at the **Full Example** I posted.

Comment: @Karlioh - there was a reason I said you should remove the trailing `'\n'` from `textStream`. Look at the differences in `main` `:p` (it will cause your character count in `len` to be off by `1` and then for your `space` count to be off by `1`). (you can add `'\n'` to `delim` as another way to fix it)

Comment: The code is almost perfect, except the first index of the array is never sorted.

Comment: Ok, you have me a bit confused. When I sort `the quick brown fox...` I get `a brown dog fox jumped...`. There the first index `the` **is** sorted. Are you not getting the same results?

Comment: When I input "I have a lot of stuff" I get "I" a, have, lot, of, stuff. So most of it is sorted except the first index.

Comment: Let me look at it from that standpoint. There is nothing that immediately jumps out as to why you are having that issue. I just typed in `i want a cup of tea` and got back `a cup i of tea want`. Did you add `'\n'` to `delim` ? **Oh, oh..** there is nothing wrong, it is just sorting by local with `Capital` letters first. We can adjust the sort. Just change `strcmp` to `strcasecmp`!

Comment: See the updated answer. You use `strcasecmp` in `compare_str` if you want a case insensitive sort. `:-)` Using a captial `I` in `I want a cup of tea` I get `a cup I of tea want` now.

Comment: Now that I've made that change I get an error saying  "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external symbol _strcasecmp". I also get a warning saying strcasecmp() is undefined.

Comment: Huh? you have `#include <string.h>` and you are calling `strcasecmp` just as I have it, right? Unless you have some strange version of libc, you shouldn't be getting that error unless you have a typo. Look at `man strcasecmp` on your system and make sure `#include <string.h>` is all that is required. (should be).

Comment: I'm completely lost, I have it just as you have it.                                           int compare_str (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
     
 return strcasecmp(*ia, *ib);

Comment: Use `stricmp` instead. `strcasecmp` is the non-standard Linux version of the non-standard `stricmp` widows version`:-)` That is the fun you run into between the platforms. Usually I would complain about the lack of standards compliance by the darkside, but since there isn't a standard, each platform just implements the same thing a little differently. (disregard `man strcasecmp` -- you definitely will NOT have it)

Comment: That just goes to show you that even a blind squirrel can find a nut every once in a while.... Of all the languages you look at in your programming life, none will give you the flexibility and power that C does. Oh sure, 'new' languages may appear to make life easier by giving you the latest gee-whiz functions, classes, etc, but at the end to the day, there will always be round holes where the new square gee-whiz functions don't fit. You won't ever have that problem with C. It takes a little more time to learn, but the education is well worth the effort. Good luck!